# Spring security bypass css images

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring http security, I am facing problem while bypass css,images and other resources.

My security xml file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http pattern="resources" security="none" />
    <http auto-config="true">
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/campaign/list" authentication-failure-url="/loginError"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login" />              
    </http>

    <!-- <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/main*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_REGULAR_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/main"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginError"/>
    </http> -->

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>    

</beans:beans>
```

I have tried with

```
<http security="none" pattern="/resources/css/style.css"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/resources*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" /> 
<security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
```

But these are not working 
Please let me know what code I can use to bypass resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
<http pattern="resources" security="none" />
```

But you must be sure that all things under this pattern can be public.

Comment: I have added that but still not getting sucess. I have put your changes in question code also

Comment: And with this? <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" /> . Wich spring security version are you using?

Comment: I am using spring 4.0.6 release.

Comment: <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" /> is also not working

Comment: 4.0.6.Release probably is a version of Spring framework but non your version of Spring security. Latest stable is 3.2.6, you can check it out in http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `<intercept-url>` for static resources as below:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" filters="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the previously suggested

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
```

you need to define the `/resources/` directory as an MVC resource as well, if you haven't done it yet. In your MVC configuration (if you use XML configuration), add the following resource mapping:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

See [Serving of resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) for further info.